# Chromecast crashes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, crash, chromecast

I'm working on a social wall that is powered by the Google Chromecast. Everything is working well, but after a few minutes the Chromecast suddenly crashes without any errors.

I set up a custom receiver app and a sender app. The sender app basically just starts the receiver app and has no other function.

The receiver app is built upon Backbone and Marionette. It also uses Socket.io to communicate with a server, that provides the contents like tweets, Instagramm pictures and so on.
The app works like a slideshow, it iterates over the contents, shows images, and animates things with the help of css transitions.

It seems like the Chromecast can handle these things, since it runs quite smoothly. But just before the Chromcast crashes the app begins to stutter, freezes and finally reboots.

I thought that maybe a memory leak could have caused the crash, so I investigated the JavaScript object allocations and memory distribution, but everything seems to be ok. There is no memory leak recognizable.

As mentioned, neither the JavaScript engine nor the Chromecast itself provides any error message. (You can find the Chromecast log below.)

One more thing: I tried to run the app without displaying all the images, and it didn't crash for a period of I guess 15min. But I cannot exclude that the app won't crash without the images.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

```
[140530 11:07:02.04] [4484.276s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:08.00] [4490.235s] [cv2.MdnsService] [INFO] onDeviceList returned 0 devices

[140530 11:07:08.03] [4490.264s] [cv2.MdnsService] [INFO] onDeviceList returned 1 devices

[140530 11:07:08.03] [4490.270s] [cv2.DiscoveryService] [INFO] onDevicesFinished

[140530 11:07:08.06] [4490.293s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:14.05] [4496.288s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:20.05] [4502.292s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:26.06] [4508.295s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:32.06] [4514.300s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:40.96] [4523.202s] [cv.DialService] [INFO] onDeviceList returned 1 devices

[140530 11:07:42.10] [4524.342s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:44.54] [4526.773s] [cv.DeviceDescriptionService] [INFO] [fetchDeviceDescription]: GET http://10.10.0.145:8008/ssdp/device-desc.xml => 200 (OK)

[140530 11:07:44.54] [4526.778s] [cv.DeviceDescriptionService] [INFO] Device description: <?xml version="1.0"?><root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
<specVersion>
    <major>1</major>
    <minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>
<URLBase>http://10.10.0.145:8008</URLBase>
<device>
    <deviceType>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:device:dial:1</deviceType>
    <friendlyName>Weidenscreen</friendlyName>
    <manufacturer>Google Inc.</manufacturer>
    <modelName>Eureka Dongle</modelName>
    <UDN>***</UDN>
    <iconList>
        <icon>
            <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
            <width>98</width>
            <height>55</height>
            <depth>32</depth>
            <url>/setup/icon.png</url>
        </icon>
    </iconList>
    <serviceList>
        <service>
            <serviceType>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:serviceId:dial</serviceId>
            <controlURL>/ssdp/notfound</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/ssdp/notfound</eventSubURL>
            <SCPDURL>/ssdp/notfound</SCPDURL>
        </service>
    </serviceList>
</device>
</root>

[140530 11:07:44.54] [4526.782s] [cv.DeviceDescriptionService] [INFO] Caching device description for 2

[140530 11:07:44.55] [4526.784s] [cv2.DiscoveryService] [INFO] onDevicesFinished

[140530 11:07:47.14] [4529.374s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:53.15] [4535.383s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:07:58.00] [4540.235s] [cv2.MdnsService] [INFO] onDeviceList returned 0 devices

[140530 11:07:58.03] [4540.265s] [cv2.MdnsService] [INFO] onDeviceList returned 1 devices

[140530 11:07:58.03] [4540.270s] [cv2.DiscoveryService] [INFO] onDevicesFinished

[140530 11:08:04.02] [4546.261s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:08:13.69] [4555.927s] [cv2.CastChannelService] [INFO] Got message from {"channelId":1,"readyState":"open","url":"casts://10.10.0.145:8009"}

[140530 11:08:13.70] [4555.933s] [cv.PopupMenuService] [INFO] Popup request: init

[140530 11:08:13.71] [4555.943s] [cv.RampDiscoveryService] [INFO] Discovering DIAL/RAMP activity now...

[140530 11:08:13.75] [4555.985s] [cv2.CastService] [INFO] there are 1 receivers

[140530 11:08:13.75] [4555.991s] [cv.DialService] [INFO] chrome.dial.discoverNow = true

[140530 11:08:13.75] [4555.992s] [cv.DialService] [INFO] onDeviceList returned 1 devices

[140530 11:08:13.76] [4555.995s] [cv2.DiscoveryService] [INFO] onDevicesFinished

[140530 11:08:14.17] [4556.411s] [cv2.DialClient] [INFO] [GetAppInfo]: GET http://10.10.0.145:8008/apps/ => 204 (No Content)
```

Comment: Please contact us at https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?rd=1 to further assist you with the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and was fixed by a simple reset to the chromecast itself. there is a small reset button on it that will allow you to do so if you press it for about 10 seconds. If you do so, you will have to set it up all over again. Also check for software updated for the chromecast from Google. Good luck.